# vscode cannot jump to function definition

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I wrote `fileOp.py` in a folder. I added it to the `python` path.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert('fileOp_location')
```

In a new python file `test.py`, I imported fileOp.
I use `from fileOp import class_in_fileOp.py`

The `test.py` file can be executed normally. But I use `ctrl+ fileOp`  to jump to the `fileOp.py` file.
I can jump to other files normally. For example, `import re`. I can jump to the `re.py` file normally by `ctrl+re`. Note that when I run test.py normally. The functions and classes in fileOp can be executed normally. But it cannot jump.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem? Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you need to enter `fileOp_location` in some search path in the settings of a Python plugin of VS Code.

Comment: If you have to manipulate `sys.path` to run your code there might be something wrong with your project setup.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can you give more details? For example, how to find possible locations of incorrect settings?

Comment: search settings for `python path` and pick the `autocomplete` setting